# Java code to encrypt a given sting

Tags: java

I want a java code to encrypt a given string using 2 main strings like below

```
s1 = "qwertyuiopasdfghjklzxcvbnm";
s2 = "mnbvcxzasdfghjklpoiuytrewq";
```

If our input string is `"mnb"`,  then it is compared with `s2` and the same index in `s1` is added 3 then output will be `"rty"` but I am not getting proper output.

Can any one help me to solve this problem?

```
public static void main(String[] args){
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    String s1 = "qwertyuiopasdfghjklzxcvbnm";
    String s2 = "mnbvcxzasdfghjklpoiuytrewq";
    String input,out = "";
    System.out.println("enter input string");
    input = sc.nextLine();
    for(int i=0;i<s2.length();i++){
        if(input.charAt(i)==s2.charAt(i)){
            out+=s1.charAt(i+3);
        }
        System.out.println(out);
    }
    sc.close();
}
```

Comment: i'm sorry but I don't really understand what you're trying to achieve... where does the index 3 come from?

Comment: if my input is "m" then m is searched with s2 ,if m is found in s2 at 1 then in s1 at first index is q.q after 3rd letter will be output

Comment: ok now i think i know what you want to do...

Comment: Why dont you use `patterns` and `matchers` to read the input string in your another string?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need an extra loop to check which character matches from `s2` string.Other than that,you will have to use `modulo` operator to avoid `ArrayIndexOutOfBound`.

Try this

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        String s1 = "qwertyuiopasdfghjklzxcvbnm";
        String s2 = "mnbvcxzasdfghjklpoiuytrewq";
        String input, out = "";
        System.out.println("enter input string");
        input = sc.nextLine();
        for (int i = 0; i < input.length(); i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < s2.length(); j++) {
                if (input.charAt(i) == s2.charAt(j)) {
                     out += s1.charAt((j + 3)%26);
                }
            }

        }
        System.out.println(out);
        sc.close();
    }
```

**UPDATE**

As pointed in comment by @ParkerHalo,to handle `ArrayIndexOutOfBound`,you can use `modulo` operator like this

```
out += s1.charAt((j + 3)%26);
```

Comment: No you don't need an extra loop... This code delivers a StringIndexOutOfBoundsException for input `"q"`.

Answer (score 2):

You almost had the solution! The problem is when you input one of the last 3 characters of s2 you'll have to use the modulo operator (when the position gets larger than 25 you will reach the end of the string and have to start searching at the beginning!)

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    String s1 = "qwertyuiopasdfghjklzxcvbnm";
    String s2 = "mnbvcxzasdfghjklpoiuytrewq";
    String input,out = "";
    System.out.println("enter input string");
    input = sc.nextLine();
    for (int i = 0; i < input.length(); i++) {
        int position = s2.indexOf(input.charAt(i));
        position = (position + 3) % 26;
        out = out + s1.charAt(position);
    }
    sc.close();
}
```

In order to avoid wrong user input you should check the `position` if it's `-1` (if the character is not found in `s2`) and handle that case properly (exception/outprint + break in the loop)